# Android LocationManager.isProviderEnabled() always returns false

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have an application that uses a Network provider for its location. Every time the apps starts it checks to see whether the Network provider is enabled using `isProviderEnabled()` method in LocationManager.

If it returns false I present an alert to the user to enable Network Provider and then use the application. This logic had been working really well, with a few exceptions with non-Google certified devices(not a concern since they usually do not have Maps API either). Lately, with some devices on ICS and now on JellyBean emulator, I get a consistent "false" for `isProviderEnabled()` even though it is enabled.

I have since moved to use the string returned from 
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED)) to see whether it contains "network". It is a hack but it is working for now. I would love to be able to use `isProviderEnabled()` method.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: I am also facing this issue! You got any work around for it?

Answer (score 2):

@naqi @gkris
I also noticed this issue where `isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` was returning `false`.
Solution to this is to also ask user to set the `Location Method` to `High Accuracy` instead of `Battery Saving` or `Device Only`

This setting is available under location settings and has different name on different devices. On some devices that I have tested on, this setting is with name `Mode`, `Location Mode`, `Location Method` etc Also the value can be `High Accuracy` or `GPS` or `GPS, Wifi and Mobile Networks`

Developers will have to train users on this.

Answer (score 1):

From the API doc for : LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

> This provider determines location using satellites.  Depending on
>   conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix.
>   Requires the permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

So if you're not requiring ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION it will return false.